# How to sort a List<string> based on the string after last index of the string c#

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to be able to re-order a list based on the lastindexof a character in this case "/".

```
var ListToSort = new List<string> { "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/2toe0685tcr1/Hello_1",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/xdt42pj616ao/Yes_1",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/7yhzozo2rgu5/Hello_2",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/atrejl1rzliq/Yes_2",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/bgwq9i8fbsj4/Hello_3",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/4rrx4pldbiq1/Zues_1"};
```

im wanting to sort the list based on the last index of "/" eg it would compare Yes_1,Hello_2 and so on , the expected output would be:

```
            
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/2toe0685tcr1/Hello_1
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/7yhzozo2rgu5/Hello_2
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/bgwq9i8fbsj4/Hello_3
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/xdt42pj616ao/Yes_1
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/atrejl1rzliq/Yes_2
            Hjgs/dasdf/ada/4rrx4pldbiq1/Zues_1
```

edit : working solution from comments

```
ListToSort = ListToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("/"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Use Linq `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.

Comment: `ListToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("/")))`

Comment: What specific programming problem are you running into? Do you not know how to find the last index of the character? How to sort a list? Each of those problems has SO questions with good answers.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YLrSnj

Comment: @PoulBak - why ThenBy ?

Comment: Would be better if you'd have also provided `Hello_11` in your sample list, because that will come before `Hello_2` with string sorting.

Comment: `ListToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("/")))` this worked thanks!

Comment: please add the working solution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - gotta learn from the mistake in the future :)

Comment: @RandRandom: `ThenBy` only if needed - in the example there are no duplicates, but could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ListToSort = new List<string> { "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/2toe0685tcr1/Hello_1",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/xdt42pj616ao/Yes_1",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/7yhzozo2rgu5/Hello_2",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/atrejl1rzliq/Yes_2",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/bgwq9i8fbsj4/Hello_3",
            "Hjgs/dasdf/ada/4rrx4pldbiq1/Zues_1"};
        
        foreach(var item in ListToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("/"))))
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ListToSort = ListToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("/"))).ToList();` if you don't wanna do foreach :)